# How can I tell if my device doesn't see beacons?

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I'm creating an iOS 7 app that will react to nearby beacons. However, I need to consider users that have an iPhone 4 or any other device that will not detect beacons. How can I tell if the device my app is running on supports beacons?

Comment: I'm not positive but perhaps you can use the `CBPeripheralManager state`.

Comment: Looking at this, it appears that this is the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  CBCentral manager state. If it is `CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported` it doesn't support BLE.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monitor or range for beacons you might want to check if monitoring is available via CoreLocation Framework - Here is the way to do it :

if (![CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]) {

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Monitoring not available" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        return;

}

else{
//Monitoring is available
}